# gridview data manuplation via web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ext.net

I am wondering how other developers do this, that's why I ask it .

I am thinking I am doing wrong ,I guess,

Here is the secanario:

I have a grid with pagination feature (remote pagination via web servis asmx).

I have a form, when I click it, it loads the grid values client side ,and send to web service ,after inserting data ,I load all grid values connected web service again.

It seems to me redundancy and not make sense.it is same all controls also (combox,grid,list..).

Is it possible to send the form particular data row and send back to grid only edited row and put it there instead of loading all data again.

Comment: Yes it is, but you need to implement it manually, you can access the new row data with events and save it by calling the service through an Ajax request

Comment: hmm,which is better ,reload all data again or this one u mentioned.which one generally do u apply.(I guess we are talking about ext.net),have u any example on about this technics,thank you again ,friend for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please investigate [this example](http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Saving_Variations/WebService/).

Comment: danil tahnk you ,whats your persenol expreiance , generally  this kind of approach make the project more professinal ,is it comman approach for profosianle web sites thank you again